# Google Static Maps Issue: Geodesic path having corners

Tags: polyline, google-maps-static-api, geodesic-sphere

I am having issues with geodesic path/polylines with Google Static Maps.

Buggy map with corners:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&size=512x380&zoom=1&path=geodesic:true|25.06,-80.86|-43.87,151.21|64.13,-21.82|39.9,110.41|41,9

[image: Bug in Google Static Maps]

When removing the first coordinate, i am getting nice path lines:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&size=512x380&zoom=1&path=geodesic:true|-43.87,151.21|64.13,-21.82|39.9,110.41|41,9

[image: Bug in Google Static Maps]

When removing the last coordinate, it stays buggy with different corners.

I cannot find anything about a reported Google bug, but I have no idea what could be wrong with my URLs.

Any ideas? Google? Can you help?

Comment: I filed a Google Bug Report and they accepted it as a bug. So I guess we need to wait until they fix it.